# Html.BeginForm with multiple htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the Html.BeginForm and passing in a css class as per below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" } ))
```

that works fine, but I want to add a returnURL querystring parameter after it but that doesn't seem to work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))
```

how can I add multiple htmlAttributes so that I can tell it my css class and a querystring parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of `BeginForm`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account", 
        new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, 
        new { @class = "form"}))
```